# Load wordpress through specific URL path from subdirectory using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

## The goal

Visting `www.DOMAIN.com/blog` to load Wordpress from a directory named "/wp-blog" or similar. Also another rule is the host must match a specific domain.

### Current rules

This does **not** seem to be working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^blog [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?DOMAIN.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp-blog [PT,L]
```

Any ideas what we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was actually simple

The rules just needed altering slightly and I had to *actually* change the /blog directory name as some other rules were causing apache to get confused.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ /wp_blog/$1 [L]
```

Also had to update htaccess for the Wordpress install as well to reference `wp_blog`